# Mysterious change of value in pointer vector

Tags: c, pointers

As homework I have to implement a function that receives two vectors of pointers. It should compare the values contained in the memory address pointed by these pointers and return TRUE or FALSE if they are all the same or not.

For this I have created this function:

```
tBoolean comparePointerVector(int *v1[], int *v2[]) {       
    int i;
    tBoolean status = TRUE;

    for (i=0;i<MAX_DELIVERIES;i++) {
        if(*v1[i]!=*v2[i]) {            
            status = FALSE;
            break;
        }        
    }
    return status;
}
```

The method compiles fine but always crashes in the first iteration. Investigating the problem I have found a very strange phenomena. Adding the next code before entering the for loop, the printed results for both lines are different, which is very surprising for me:

```
printf("value %d\n   ",*v1[0]);
printf("value %d\n   ",*v1[0]);
```

The first line prints correctly the value pointed by v1[0], but the second line prints the memory address. How is this possible that the they don't print the same?

Besides this why this code seems to break my program?

```
*v1[i]!=*v2[i]
```

I ask here in the same question because I think both questions are related.

EDIT:

Definition of MAX_DELIVERIES in a file called data.h

```
#define MAX_DELIVERIES 50
```

Calling the function:

```
tBoolean pd_equals(tProductDeliveries pd1, tProductDeliveries pd2){

    //For maintenability and better understading this method contains several 'return' statements.
    if(pd1.poductID!=pd2.poductID) {

        return FALSE;

    } else if(pd1.totalPurchases!=pd2.totalPurchases) {

        return FALSE;

    } else if(pd1.totalSales!=pd2.totalSales) {

        return FALSE;

    } else if(pd1.total!=pd2.total) {

        return FALSE;

    } else if(comparePointerVector(pd1.sales, pd2.sales) != TRUE) {

        return FALSE;

    } else if(comparePointerVector(pd1.purchases, pd2.purchases) != TRUE) {

        return FALSE;        
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Calling the pd_equals method:

```
    pd_getProductDeliveries(deliveries, 123, &pd1); 
    if(pd_equals(pd1, pd1)==TRUE) {
        printf("\n\t-> OK\n");
        passedTest[0]++;
    } else {
        printf("\n\t-> FAIL.\n");
    }
```

Comment: Your example printf lines are exactly the same. Are you sure they print out different values?

Comment: Yes, the same code executed twice results in different prints. Hence the mystery.

Comment: You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: also, `MAX_DELIVERIES` is important. Show how yo call the function.

Comment: Is your local `sizeof(int)` the same as `sizeof(int *)`? If not, the stack gets messed up because you are printing a pointer with `%d`. Try again with the proper formatting specifier `%p`.

Comment: printf("value %p\n   ",*v1[0]);
    printf("value %p\n    ",*v1[0]); Produces: value 000000000000007B
   value 000000000022C6B0, Still different, but I am trying to write the value in the memory address of v1, which should be an int, isn't it?

Comment: I can see that: sizeof(int) = 4         sizeof(int *) = 8

Comment: Can you show us the code that sets pd1.sales? It looks like it may be the address of a stack variable that went out of scope. That's why calling printf is clobbering it.

Comment: Same thing with pd1.purchases.

Comment: Is it possible the system("PAUSE") has any influence? I am still getting the same result.

Comment: Time to use a debugger and see how your memory is being corrupted by something else in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your answers. I got it fixed but now I am even more puzzled.

I just have removed the `system("PAUSE");` I had between the two `printf` and now both print exactly the same. I am sorry I didn't post it in my code but I thought it was totally irrelevant.

Now my next question would be: What in the world is the `system("PAUSE")` doing that messes up the memory?

Comment: It would be helpful to edit the question to show us *everything* that's between those two identical printf statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is caused by the comparison if(*v1[i]!=*v2[i]). It must be

```
v1[i] != v2[i] or *(v1+i) != *(v2+i)
```